# Java: How to draw in a canvas?

Tags: java, swing, canvas, awt

I'm new to Java and I want to make a simple game where there are squares in a simple grid (something between a snake and a labyrinth). The number of squares doesn't change, only their color does.

I already programmed the objects I need for the game. Now  I want to display the game.

I know how to create a JFrame, a JPanel and a JButton, which I will need, but I don't understand how to draw in a canvas.

I made a test class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Test extends Canvas {
    public static void main (String[] arg) {
        JFrame f=new JFrame();
        f.setTitle("Title");
        f.setSize(400,500);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setVisible(true);
        JPanel pan=new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        pan.add(new JButton("hey"));
        Test canvas=new Test();
        Graphics g=canvas.getGraphics();
        canvas.paint(g);
        pan.add(canvas);
        f.setContentPane(pan);
    }

    public Test() {
        setBackground (Color.green);
        setSize(300,300);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        Color c = g.getColor();
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect(10,10,80,80);
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillRect(150,50,80,80);
        g.setColor(c);
    }
}
```

When I run this, a windows is created, with the correct title , size and button, but there isn't anything else (no green background, no red or blue rectangle), and an error is detected :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Test.paint(Test.java:25)
    at Test.main(Test.java:15)
```

What am I doing wrong ? Is there a better way to draw these squares ?

Thanks !

Comment: Canvas is an AWT Component. You should use a JPanel instead

Comment: 1) `Graphics g=canvas.getGraphics();` As an aside, this comes up almost daily, as does the advice not to use AWT components in Swing GUIs. Pretty much anything that could be done in a `Canvas` can be done in a `JPanel` (and better). 2) `f.setVisible(true);` should be done after all components are added..

Comment: "Canvas is an AWT Component. You should use a JPanel instead": why???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Comment these two lines

```
 //Graphics g=canvas.getGraphics();
 //canvas.paint(g);
```

And change the paint method as follows.

```
 @Override
 public void paint(Graphics g) {
     super.paint(g);
```

Rest is all fine. Hope it helps you to progress.